# Using epsilon delta definition show $a_n=\frac{2(n!)}{n^n}$ converges to $0$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Given $\epsilon >0$ there exists an $N$ such that for all $n>N,\vert {2(n!)\over n^n}\vert < \epsilon$ and this is where I get stuck I know that the function is decreasing but I can't seem to find an $N$ that works.

Comment: Could you correctly format your question for easier readability?

Comment: sorry about that

Comment: There is no $\epsilon$-$\delta$ in the sequences. It should be $\epsilon$-$N$ definition.

Comment: If i works with $N $, it will work for $N+1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**hint**

$$\frac {n!}{n^n}=\frac {1.2.3...n}{n.n.n...n} $$
$$\leq \frac {1}{n} $$

let $\epsilon>0$ given.

it is sufficient to look for $N $ such that

$$n>N\implies \frac {2}{n}<\epsilon$$
or
$$n>N\implies n>\frac {2}{\epsilon} $$

we can take
$$N=\lfloor \frac {2}{\epsilon} \rfloor+1$$
or any other greater.

Comment: $N=\lfloor \frac {2}{\epsilon}\rfloor +1$

Comment: so if $N= \vert2/\epsilon\vert +1$ then for all $n>N$ we have $2/n+1 < 2/N+1 < 2/\epsilon +1$ i feel like i'm missing something

Comment: $n>N\implies n>2/epsilon\implies 2/n <\epsilon $

Comment: so then why is the +1 necessary in N

Comment: To be sure that if $n\geq N $ then $n>2/epsilon $.

Comment: im so lost thanks for the help but I still have no clue what is going on

Comment: @Rerock look now i just edited it.